# Coding a logo in PDF file using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'm using XSLT to output a document in PDF.
On the page header I need to add a jpeg company logo, does anybody know how to do this:
below is my page header format:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
    <fo:block font-family = "Courier" font-size =>
        <fo:table>
            <fo:table-column column-width = "15mm"/>
            <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
```

I'm new to XSLT so I'd appreciate some help :-)

Comment: Have you tried inserting fo:external-graphic inside fo:block? The link to specification is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_external-graphic

Comment: I tried this but there is certainly something wrong I've done:

Comment: <fo:block>
 <fo:external-graphic = "C:\\Desktop\image.jpeg"/>
 </fo:block>

Comment: Any other hint?

Comment: Try <fo:block> <fo:external-graphic src="url(file:/C:/Desktop/image.jpeg)"/> </fo:block>. You are missing `src` attribute.

Comment: `font-size =` is not a well-formed attribute: Its value is missing.

Comment: Hi Joe, Tmakita, thanks for your comments but it still doesn't work... any other hint?

Comment: Could you show us the latest XSL-FO that you tried?

Comment: There are multiple graphics samples in the 'XSL-FO Samples' page at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples#graphics. They might help you with the syntax.